# AR(1) Time Series Model and Reverse Causality

Tags: time-series, regression, causality

I came across a  research where the authors hypothesized that x will cause y. The team used self-assessment survey questions to collect all the data on x and y. At time point 1, they asked respondents questions to measure both x and y (x1 and y1). At time point 2, they recontacted the same group respondents but only asked questions used to measure y (y2).

I think, in theory, it is possible that y could cause x, which leads y an endogenous variable.

To test their hypothesis, the authors constructed three regression models:

model 1: y1 = a*x1 + e (a is positive and statistically sig)

model 2: y2 = b*x1 + f (b is positive and statistically sig)

model 3: y2 = c*x1 + d*y1 + g (both c and d are positive and statistically sig, and c is smaller than a and b).

The authors deemed that model 3 as an AR model and argued that since the coefficient of x1 in model 3 (c) is still positive and significant given y1 is controlled, the effect of x on y is robust and this helps them establish the causal order).

My questions are:
1)Can the AR model (model 3) along with the two simple OLS (model 1 & 2) address the concern of reverse causality?
2)Had the author collected x at time point 2 (x2) and run the same three models with x and y's position switched (x as DV and y as IV), mathematically would it possible for us to find that all coefficients of y are positive and statistically significant, which potentially could be used to support the reversed causal story: x cause y.
3)In model 1 and 2, they found x1 has significant effect on both y1 and y2. Would using y1 and x1 as predictors in model 3 leave room for biased estimate, given the authors' theoretical model?
4)I know that finding an instrumental variable for a two-stage leas squared model is a rather common practice to address endogeneity concerns, can lagged time series variable do the same trick? I found some "ad hoc" solution using lagged time series variable to deal with this problem, but the models usually were specified as:

```
     y2 = a*x1 + e
     y2 = b*x2 + f
```

Did I get it wrong?

Thank you in advance for any insights here.

Comment: It might help to add the research paper you are referring to :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your description well, the paper has some assumptions (hypothesis):

- X_i causes Y_i
- The effect of X_i -> Y_i is linear
- X_i also causes Y_{i+1}

Regarding the OLS:  A linear model only captures linear correlations. If Y_i causes X_i, you'll still get positive and statistically significant coefficients.

Regarding the AR: If X_i causes (or at least correlates linearly with) Y_i, and Y_i causes (or at least correlates linearly with) Y_{i+1}, X_i causes indirectly (and correlates with) Y_{i+1}. Adjusting for Y_i in would mainly estimate the direct of effect of X_i to Y_{i+1}, thus what remains besides the linear effect of Y_i on Y_{i+1}.

But the argumentation is not complete. X could cause Y, or Y could cause X. Being able to predict Y given X is consistent with X causing Y. But it doesn't disprove that Y causes X, and thus doesn't prove that X causes Y.

In logical reasoning, we have statements A="X causes Y" and B ="a correlation exists between X and Y", where we know that A => B. If one then observes B (be able to fit the above models) doesn't imply A. If A=>B, knowing B doesn't give any information about A. However, if not B, you do know for sure that A isn't true.

Therefore, it seems they'd better assume that "Y causes X", and then do the same analysis. If those estimated effects are **not** significant, it contradicts with "Y causes X", thus proving that "Y doesn't cause X" (at least not with a linear effect).

If the observations match with X causing Y, and do not match with Y causing X, you could state that X is more likely to cause Y than Y causing X. (with the assumptions that the effect is constant).